# Deleting first column with vim

Tags: command-line, vim, text-processing

I have a text file.

```
number 1_1 \t number1_2 \t etc
number 2_1 \t number2_2 \t etc
```

I want to remove the first column of this file (corresponding to number1_1, number2_1 etc, ie the numbers before the first tab for each row). I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896637/vim-trying-to-remove-the-first-column-of-a-document) that proposes a solution to delete the first column (see Peter's answer). However, it doesn't work for me as the numbers have different sizes and I cannot repeat the operation to delete the first column. How can I do then?

Comment: Do you want a vim specific solution?

Comment: preferably, but not necessarily (what else do you propose?)

Comment: @bigTree do you want command line answers?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Command line answers would be good thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should delete all chars before and including the 1st tab on any line:

`:%s/^[^\t]*\t//`

Command line `cut`:

```
cut -f 2- {filename.txt} > {filenamenew.txt}
```

cut defaults to tabs; if you want something else like a space add `-d " "`. 
`-f` is fields to copy over. 2- means all from (and including) column 2.

Answer (score 4):

Through `awk`,

```
awk -F"\t" '{print FS,$2}' file > newfile
```

It cuts the first column and prints only the remaining tab and  second column.

Through `sed`,

```
sed -r 's/^([^\t]*)\t(.*)$/\t\2/g' file > newfile
```

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/472332/deleting-first-column-with-vim/472339?noredirect=1#comment625630_472332

Answer (score 4):

`:%s/[^\t]*\t//`

On every line (`%`), replace (`s/ORIGINAL/REPLACEMENT/`) the first occurrence of “non-tab characters (`[^\t]`, in any number (`*`)) followed by a tab `\t`” by nothing. You can type <kbd>Tab</kbd> instead of `\t`.

Alternatively you can match the shortest sequence of characters (`.\{-}`) ending in a tab. `.*\t` would match the longest match for `.*`, so it would match all but the last column; `.\{-}` matches the shortest match which is the first column.

`:%s/.\{-}\t//`

Comment: @lobi No. It's the `%` at the beginning that means “for all lines”. A `g` at the end would repeat the substitution, so it would repeatedly remove the first column until only the last column remains.

Answer (score 3):

In Vi to remove first column (separated by space), you can do:

```
:%norm dW
```

for a column separated by <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it's:

`:%norm df`<kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>

So the command which would remove the first column from file (in-place) can be:

```
ex +"%norm df$(echo -e '\t')" -scwq file
```

<sup>To check the output before saving (dry-run), replace `-scwq` with `-sc'%p|q!'`.</sup>

Or based on [Chris suggestion](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5139/467), like:

```
ex -c':exe ":%norm df\<Tab>"' -sc'%p|q!' <(echo -e "a a\tb b\tc c")
```

---

Alternatively do it in visual mode (if starting from the top-left):

1. Enter visual-block by <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd>.
2. Jump at the end and select first column by pressing: <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd> (or adjust manually).
3. Press <kbd>d</kbd> to delete the selected block.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the remaining space before the second column I suggest:

`:%norm df`<kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>`x`