# How to delete second column in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have a tab-delimited file like:

```
name1   verb1   name2   verb2   etc...
```

I want to delete the second column. I tried editing one of [these answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472332/deleting-first-column-with-vim), but being not familiar with `sed` and `awk`, I couldn't.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: @KasiyA the OP's original used \t to indicate tabs.

Comment: @steeldriver Ok you are right. I thought it's part of line. removed. But I edited to correct one according to [first post](http://askubuntu.com/revisions/531271/1).thanks

Comment: vim visual-block mode doesn't solve the problem? (ctrl-v in normal mode, select the column, `x` to delete)?

Comment: @Rmano it helps thanks, but could you tell me how to go to the end of the file in visual mode? (I tried ctrl G, but it doesn't work).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In vim, you should be able to use the command

```
:%s/\t[^\t]*//
```

(substitute <kbd>TAB</kbd> followed by zero or more occurrences of any character except <kbd>TAB</kbd> with nothing). If your file has only two columns you could use a slightly simpler `:%s/\t.*` or `:%s/\t.*$`which replace the first <kbd>TAB</kbd> and *any* following characters up to the end of the line.

Answer (score 31):

The accepted answer is much more elegant than this (I upvoted it!) but if you do not remember it  you can use `vim` [visual block mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html) directly. Open vim and go (normal mode) to the first corner of the column, like this:

[image]

Type `CTRL-V` and you can move the cursor to select the column, this is midway:

[image]

To go at the end, press `G`:

[image]

the block seems broken because we are on the last line which is blank; simply go up one line (with the up arrow or `k`) to see it again...:

[image]

Now you simply press `x` to delete the block:

[image]

Comment: Ugh, this didn't work for me. For some reason the column selection seemed to work, but then it deleted to the end of the line. I used another technique which I will post.

Answer (score 6):

I would use `cut` for this

```
cut -f1,3- file.txt > newfile.txt
mv newfile.txt file.txt
```

You can use this as a filter within vim, too (this will replace all the lines in the file; you could also use (for example) `2,9` instead of `%` to process lines 2-9, or select the lines you want with `V`):

```
:%!cut -f1,3-
```

`-f1,3-` means 'print field one, followed by field three and all fields until the end of the row'. By default, `cut` uses a tab as its delimiter; if you need something else, use the `-d` option (see `man cut`).

Answer (score 5):

You can try either:

```
:%norm WdW
```

or manually using visual mode:

1. Jump into second column (e.g. by pressing: <kbd>W</kbd>).
2. Start visual-block by <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd>.
3. Select second column (e.g. by pressing: <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd>).
4. Delete it by pressing <kbd>d</kbd>.

---

To do it in-place from the command line, try:

```
$ ex +':exe ":%norm f\<Tab>dE"' -scx file
```

<sup>Related: [How to write literal for Tab key to use for motion?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5137/467)</sup>

See also:

- [Delete a specific Column in VIM/gvim with out using Visual Block mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10514864/55075)

Comment: Yes, +1, but beware that if you have blank lines at the end step 3) can go awry...

Answer (score 0):

To delete a column starting 83 characters from the left, up to the 94th character, you can try this (*move your cursor around until you get to the sides of the columns you want to delete, and use Control-G to see what your cursor's position is*):

```
:%s/\(^.\{83}\).\{11}/\1/
```

In short: Match the first 83 characters in each line, remember what was matched, now match the next 11 characters, and replace that entire bunch of 94 characters with those first matched 83 characters.

From http://www.peterscheie.com/unix/vi_del_columns.html .

More verbosely, here's the entire process: Hit the Escape key, followed by the colon, to get to the colon prompt. Now we say, "On every line `%`, we'll do a search-and-replace `s` and here's the regular expression we're going to look for `/`. Remember this next part `\(`: Starting at the beginning of the line `^`, match any character `.`, do that 83 times `\{83}`, that's the end of the remembering `\)`. Now match any character `.`, do that 11 times `\{11}`. Now I've told you what to look for, next we'll do what to replace it with `/`. Take the first thing I asked you to remember and use that to replace the stuff we matched `\1`. Finally, that's the end of our search-and-replace `/`.

But beware, in his article he talks about "colrm" as if that's part of vim, but it's not. It's a shell escape, and colrm is not on my Windows machine :-) .

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I like Magnun Leno's solution here even better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514864/delete-a-specific-column-in-vim-gvim-with-out-using-visual-block-mode