# How to use cut command inside vim

Tags: vim, macosx, cut-command

I know this should be very simple but due to some reason I am not able to get this working.

say I have a simple file with multiple columns of data, I just want to get second column and remove other columns, while I have that file opened in vim. As answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/531323/554084), I use following in vim:

```
:%!cut -f2
```

But it just shows following, but contents of file is still same.

> 6 lines filtered

See the screenshots attached:

[image]

[image]

I want to change the contents of file and have only second column there. I am using Mac.

Comment: Mac OSX is off topic here. Please use [apple.se] or [vi.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cut command assumes a tab delimited file. So you should first replace the spaces with a tab. The following will do this for you:

```
:%s/\s\+/\t/g
```

followed by the cut command that you already figured out :)

```
:%!cut -f2
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, what does it mean by `6 lines filtered`?

Comment: Because the `cut` command filtered (in this case the 2nd column out of) the (in this case 6) lines. So it basically tells you what it did :). It's not an error message.